# avgnt.exe avira gmbh

Tags: windows, anti-virus, avira

After the last update of Avira, every time I turn on the computer, I get this message of an exe file that wants to run. Even though I always uncheck the "ask me before opening this file", the message box has it checked, and it waits for my approval, which is quite annoying. What can I do do make this exe run without asking me?
[image]

Comment: WOAH! Mrror image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an [answer on the avira website](http://forum.avira.com/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=121933). But in your case you're using a newer version of Windows xp so you need to restore the local security settings in order to prevent warnings like this one.

So all you need to do in order to fix it is to write this line in
your command line:

`reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0" /v "1806" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`

[The zone 0 is your local, 1 is the internet and more.](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/58926-turn-off-open-file-security-warning/)

After that the IE will show you a meassage about your zone settings.
to remove that warning go to the regedit
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Security\
and add this key DisableSecuritySettingsCheck, set it to 1 and close it.
The zone will not make the IE show that message again.